# Pandas option for printing first and last rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I configure pandas to print the first few and last few rows of a large dataframe?

One of my computers does it. My other does not do it.

I have been through the options here but can't work out which one to use:

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/options.html

Comment: Are your versions the same?  The truncated views were added in 0.14 http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#display-changes

Comment: The version on which it doesn't have that function is 0.13.1. The other machine (which I can't access) has an older version.

Comment: I guess you could lift this class into your code, https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/b2b4015df76fad80290e87bf5c63cc620ab08a65/pandas/core/format.py#L267, I think upgrading would be simpler/better solution in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the [`max_rows` option](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/options.html#frequently-used-options)

```
pd.set_option('max_rows', 10)
```

You can also use the manual functions `.head(5)` and `.tail(5)` to see the beginning and end of a dataframe.